# Find index where both vector elements are TRUE

Tags: r

I have two vectors of TRUE and FALSE

```
a <- c("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE")
b <- c("TRUE","FALSE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","FALSE")
```

And I would like a vector returning the index where both `a` and `b` are `TRUE`

`result <-  1 4`

Comment: `which(as.logical(a) & as.logical(b))` - but really, your `a` and `b` vectors shouldn't be quoted, in which case it would be `which(a & b)`.

Comment: Or `which(a == T & b == T)`